# How do I display the timezone in js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

There is probably an obvious solution to this, but I can't figure out how to get javascript to display what time zone I'm in.

I know that d.toTimeString displays the time zone in parentheses, but it also displays the GMT offset and the seconds, neither of which I need. Also it displays time in 24 hours, which I don't want. I have already created a script that formats the time in exactly the way I want to see it, which is something like "Saturday, Nov 14, 2:36am" but I can't figure out how to add the timezone to the end of it. I want it to say "2:36am EST".

How do I do this?

Comment: can you post some code of what you've already done ?

Comment: There isn't currently a built in property or method that provides just the name of the timezone. Only one for [retrieving the offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset). Some date/time libraries have made attempts to infer the detail, but it can't typically be guaranteed to be entirely accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var d = new Date();
var timezone = /\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(d.toTimeString())[1];
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pfume4j2/

The code I used extracts the timezone value from the `d.toTimeString` using a regular expression.

Comment: For refrence, [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.totimestring) says that this is implementation-dependant so this might not work on all browsers

Comment: Also, besides just being implementation specific, the results will vary based on the date you feed it. Since you used `new Date()`, this returns the name for the *current* portion of the time zone.  For example, right now for me it returns "Pacific Standard Time", but next summer it will return "Pacific Daylight Time".

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in fiddle, the following code..

HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick="return clicked()" value="Click here">
```

JavaScript

```
function clicked()
{
    var d = new Date()
    var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();

    if(parseInt(n)<=0)
    {
        alert(d.toTimeString().split("+")[0]);
    }
    else
    if(parseInt(n)>=60)
    {
       alert(d.toTimeString().split("-")[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        alert(d.toTimeString());
    }
}
```

You can further split it more and customize it as per your requirements.

Comment: This code is not reliable depending on the person's timezone. My timezone is GMT-0500, so there is no `+`.